# Unix sed command to find multiple string patterns

Tags: text-processing, sed

Scenario here is I need to replace `"$$file_name="` value..
I have some 150 file names in a file as mentioned below..

Eg: $$file_name=abc.bbb.ccc
to_be ---> $$file_name=abc.bbb.cccV1

AS_IS :

```
$$a=abc.txt
$$file_name=abc.ddd.aaa
$$directory=/uasdua/asdsas

$$a=c.txt
$$file_name=ac.dd.ac
$$directory=/uasdua/asdsas

$$a=b.txt
$$file_name=ee.d.a
$$directory=/uasdua/asdsas
.
.
.
.
.
.
$$a=b.txt
$$directory=/uasdua/asdsas
$$file_name=e.d.a
```

to_be:

```
$$a=abc.txt
$$file_name=abc.ddd.aaaV1
$$directory=/uasdua/asdsas

$$a=c.txt
$$file_name=ac.dd.acV1
$$directory=/uasdua/asdsas

$$a=b.txt
$$file_name=ee.d.aV1
$$directory=/uasdua/asdsas
.
.
.
.
.
.
$$a=b.txt
$$directory=/uasdua/asdsas
$$file_name=e.d.aV1
```

This is what i've tried

```
select NAME from xxx where DATE='07/12/1999' > Name_file

#version will be same for that day
FILE_VERSION=`db2 -x "select version from xxx where DATE='07/12/1999'"` > version_name
FILE_VER=`cat version_name | head -1`

while read filename
 do
    FILE_NAME1=`echo ${filename}${FILE_VER}`
    sed -f pattern.txt input > output
done < file_name11
```

---

pattern.txt

```
echo "$filename"
echo "$FILE_NAME1"
s/${filename}/${FILE_NAME1}/g ---> If I hardcode this one its not working..the value is not replaced..
s/ee.d.a/ee.d.aV1/g --> this is working
```

Do i need to explictly pass it..I have 150 such file names in a file ?

---

Comment: You are mixing `sed` script shell files and shell script files. In `sed`-script files you cannot use variable replacement or `echo`. Do not use an extra sed input file but write everything in one shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would accomplish this:

```
$ sed -e '/^$$file_name/ s|$|V1|' AS_IS
```

this finds strings that start with "$file_name..". For those strings we'll do a search and replace. The `$` is the end of the string, so we're essentially appending a `V1` to each of these matched strings. You can redirect these results to a file like so:

```
$ sed -e '/^$$file_name/ s|$|V1' AS_IS > to_be
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sed -i -e 's/\$\$file_name=.*/&V1/' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..its not wrking.i have the below requirement.

Comment: @user43067 I adapted the answer.

Comment: hey thanks for the quick responce bt need an info on the below                                                          sed -f pattern.txt input > output                                                           in pattern.txt i'm using the list of commands                                                            cant i harcode that values i mean if i giv in the below format its working         s/a/b/g but if i gve in the below format.. s/$a/$b/g where $a=1 and $b=2 its not working..please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.  Worked for me:

```
sed -i 's/\$\$file_name.*/&V1/' foobar
```

where `foobar` is your input file.

Comment: Its generating error if i do the same in while loop

Comment: What kind of error?  Syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

I would write that like

```
sed -i '/^\$\$file_name=/ s/$/V1/' file
```

Comment: db2 -x "select NAME from xxx where ACCT_DT='07/12/2013'" > file_name11 FILE_VERSION=`db2 -x "select Version from xxx where date='07/12/2013'"` while read filename do echo "$filename" FILE_NAME1=`echo ${filename}${FILE_VERSION}` echo $FILE_NAME1 sed -f pattern.txt input > output done < file_name11 pattern.txt echo "$filename" echo "$FILE_NAME1" s/${filename}/${FILE_NAME1}/g                                                     but in the last line s/${filename}/${FILE_NAME1}/g is nt working..i need to explicitly pass the valueslike s/a/b/g

Comment: You can't put properly formatted code in a comment. Please edit your question.

Comment: I tried to format your code but looks like you have errors in there.  Can you format your code in the question so that we can see what mistakes you may be making and suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a "command file" with sed you can put the following in the file

```
s/\$\$file_name=.*/&V1/
```

The run the process as follow

```
sed -f pattern.txt <AS_IS >to_be
```

Comment: Error :sed: Function /^$$file_name/ s|$|V1 cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I went with:

```
while read filename
 do
echo "s/${file_name}(0)/${file_name}(${file_ver})/g" >> replaceMFNames.txt    
done < file_name11
sed -f replaceMFNames.txt inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: can you please mark this answer as the one that solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the data directly in DB2. If you want to use regular expressions, you use xQuery, and then producte the output that you want. In that way, you do not need to deal with sed.